# How to use product provided C# interface to implement the client in a good way

Tags: c#

I have little C# experience. I have at one time maintained C# code on existing project. Now I'm assigned a task of developing a C# client connecting a server installed on local host. The server provides support for user to develop client in several languages. For C++, several folders containing dlls and headers, that's enough(I know how to use). For C#, several folders of .cs files. This way I don't know how to use. They're not compiled assemblies. May I need to include all the folders and cs files one by one into my own project and build them together?  Please refer to pictures below:

C++ developer support:

[image]

C# developer support, I don't know how should I start to build a client:

[image]

The content under Support folder provides users ways to call interfaces which in turn connecting to the running server.
I'll generate a C# program using those files under Support\csharp\ folder. 
I begin in this way as picture below, not sure if it's the correct beginning? 
And about the error hint: if the namespace and the class name are same, how to instantiate it with new:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly are these screenshots supposed to be showing us?

Comment: @RonBeyer Windows File Explorer and Visual Studio! 

Comment: The first two screenshots are supporting dll or codes the product provides for users to help develop client program. I can use them. I'm not sure how to use. Sorry for the confusing. I'm trying expressing more clearly. See more screenshots.

Comment: You forgot to censor the search field in the first image :(

Comment: @JanneMatikainen Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no .csproj file, you must include them (cs files) in a C# VisualStudio project (.csproj), and compile/build them. You must know (and add) the external libraries used or deduce them from the using sentences (import's).

Then you can build that project in a external solution, and get dll to your own project, or add a new project on same solution and build them together.

---

It's a bad idea (namespace and class with the same name). Look at this SO thread: [Namespace and class with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731415/namespace-and-class-with-the-same-name). If you can't change it, you must set the path explicitly everywhere:

```
QQQClient.QQQClient quts = new QQQClient.QQQClient();
```

Comment: Thanks! You answers what I needed. And may you explain the error for me? How if the QQQClient is both a namespace and a class name? The names are defined by the product.

Comment: Thank you very much. Fully get it.