# Xamarin new project - CS0246 The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Today, I tried creating a new project. It gave me the following issue:

> "CS0246    The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

I reinstalled VS2017 and Xamarin.  It did not install the NDK, so I downloaded it and installed it. I'm not sure what else to do.

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXRiL.jpg "reference"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Namespace and class with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731415/namespace-and-class-with-the-same-name)

Comment: In the "<ProjectName>.Android" project add a reference to the "<ProjectName>" project (right click the "<ProjectName>.Android" project in Solution Explorer > Add > Reference)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if anyone else is having this issue as of 8-13-18, but the way I solved it was adding the project reference again.

Comment: I removed the reference of the project itself and re-added it. But it doesn't seem to help.