# C# Namespace question: Must avoid namespace containing any class name overlap?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I'm finding some frustration with the way C# handles namespaces when I want to reference a class whose class name happens to be identical to part of the current class's namespace. This will produce a compiler error, "'Class' is a namespace but is used like a type".

Consider the following code sample, which demonstrates the problem:

```
namespace A.B.C
{
    public class Y
    {      
    }
}

namespace X.Y.Z
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Y MyProp;
    }
}
```

In this case, I want to use the class "Y" from the namespace "A.B.C". But because "Y" is also one of the parts of the namespace, C# treats "Y" as a namespace, not a type.

I can get around this by fully qualifying the class name, "A.B.C.Y", or using an alias, but my general preference would be for C# not to treat "Y" as a namespace in this context. Often I have code, such as test code, that contains similar namespaces as classes its testing, and this kind of class/namespace collision means having to be a lot more verbose in setting things up.

I'm not sure what the process is called, but it seems that in resolving classes and namespaces, C# will walk up the namespaces until it finds a part of the namespace that matches. In this case, it walks up and finds Y. Is there a way to tell C# not to walk up, not to allow this partial namespace matching?

Comment: Use the fully qualified name in this case, or add a `using` statement for the other namespace, otherwise the compiler doesn't know if you're referencing a namespace or a class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Namespace and class with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731415/namespace-and-class-with-the-same-name)

Comment: I believe the process is called "namespace resolution" and is [documented in the C# specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/namespaces)

Comment: @MattThurston That question is asking how to organise/name namespaces and classes. However, OP seems to be implying that renaming the namespace or the class is not an option. OP, is this true?

Comment: I agree that fully qualifying the namespace of the class I'm using is a reasonable solution, it's just somewhat cumbersome. The surprising aspect of namespace resolution in this case was the seemingly "partial" namespace resolution, where it's matching on a word in the middle of the namespace. The ideal solution would be to have some way to disable this "partial" namespace matching, and require either explicit fully-qualified namespaces. So in this example, I'd prefer that "Y" on its own would not be interpreted as a namespace. If I want that namespace, I'd type "X.Y" and fully qualify it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you write `using A.B.C;` (the namespace that `Y` is in) inside `namespace X.Y.Z`, the error goes away:

```
namespace X.Y.Z
{
    using A.B.C;
    public class Class1
    {
        public Y MyProp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually really helpful, and something I didn't know. Time to go look up about using 'using' directives within a namespace, and how that differs from putting the 'using' outside the namespace...