# Differentiating class and namespace when class and namespace have the same name

Tags: c#, .net-core

```
namespace A
{
    class B
    {

    }

    class A
    {
        public void f()
        {
            A.B var = new A.B();
        }
    }
}
```

Compiled with msvc 2019 and .net core 3.1, 
this code sample gives the following error:

```
Error   CS0426  The type name 'B' does not exist in the type 'A'
```

I understand that it's better not to give the same names for classes and namespace.
But is there any way to workaround such collision?

Comment: Compiled with MSVC? This isn't C++ code.

Comment: please see this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731415/namespace-and-class-with-the-same-name

Comment: Oddly, that linked answer doesn't mention `global::`, which is the technically-correct answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should avoid a scenario where you name your classes and namespaces the same. If you can't or using third party code, you can always refer to the namespace with the `global::` keyword:

```
namespace A
{
    class B
    {

    }

    class A
    {
        public void f()
        {
            global::A.B var = new global::A.B();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to declare namespace as class `B` is already declared with the same namespace with class `A`. So just delete `A` and Visual Studio will figure out what it is desirable:

```
namespace A
{
    class B
    {

    }

    class A
    {
        public void f()
        {
            B var = new B();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

An alternative solution is:

```
using _a = A;

namespace A
{
    class B
    {

    }

    class A
    {
        public void f()
        {
            _a.B var = new _a.B();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works in this example, because they happen to live in the same namespace, but personally think @Sefe answer can be more broadly applied.

Comment: @MichalCiechan yeah, it is great solution. I've upvoted. In addition, I've updated my reply by adding an alternative way.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misunderstanding how namespaces work. You don't need to fully qualify B inside class A. You can simply refer to class B because both classes are in the same namespace. Like so:

```
namespace A
{
    class B
    {

    }

    class A
    {
        public void f()
        {
            B var = new B();
        }
    }
}
```